# Como faço para salvar latitude e longitude no Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Me disseram que tem que salvar como `double`, mas não sei como fazer,
se alguém puder me ajudar eu Agradeço :)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Marker marker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //Exibi o botão de localizar a localização do usuário

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.code_the_road_small))
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                        arg0.longitude))
                        .draggable(true).visible(true));
                 }


        });}}
```

Como faço para salvar latitude e longitude no Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja futuramente realizar uma pesquisa baseada em raio, eu recomento você utilizar o [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java).

Exemplo:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/geofire");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

geoFire.setLocation("firebase-hq", new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973));
```

Ou você pode salvar um valor double, exemplo:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/user");
ref.child("latitude").setValue(37.7853889);
ref.child("longitude").setValue(-122.4056973);
```

Firebase permite salvar dados de várias formas, recomendo você consultar a documentação deles também e que está em português.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data?hl=pt-br